# Me pueden indicar a que se debe este error, ya que instale los modulos, pero aun me marca este error en particular

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

Me podrían indicar, los pasos para inicializar este git completamente, ya que necesito parte del dicho código para un proyecto personal y me indica el siguiente error..
[image: Error]

Aquí les anexo el git, del cual estoy tratando de inicializar en reactjs.
https://github.com/tradingview/charting-library-examples.git

Comment: Hola qué tal por favor antes de 
hacer una pregunta asegúrate de haber tomado el tour, gracias  https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.